# Выполнение всех задач в Laravel Queue из кода

Tags: laravel, очередь

Всем доброго времени суток, необходимо использовать очереди в Laravel. Из коробки можно выполнять либо одну задачу из очереди, либо запускать listener и он будет выполнять задания из очереди по мере возможности. Вопрос: как можно запустить выполнение ВСЕХ задач очереди не через консоль, а из кода...